# Delete certain elements from 2 python lists using regular expressions

Tags: python

I need some help with python lists.

```
file_data=["today is good","happiness is very nice", "i am hungry","i need to go to gym"]
file_names=["_podcast_podcast_2","article_about_happiness","podcast_podcast_34","article about fitness"]
```

I need to delete elements related to "podcast". If podcast appears in file_names, delete that element and also delete corresponding element of file_data.

**required output:**

```
file_data=["happiness is very nice", "i need to go to gym"]
file_names=["article_about_happiness","article about fitness"]
```

Comment: are regular expressions a requirement?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis. About as much as a sledge hammer is for origami if you're new to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple one-liner using a list comprehension:

```
file_names, file_data = [[f, file_data[i]] for i, f in enumerate(file_names) if "podcast" not in f]
```

Output:

```
['article about fitness', 'i need to go to gym']
['article_about_happiness', 'happiness is very nice']
```

I realized that I may have misread the initial question, and gotten the output wrong.  Here is a version that results in the output listed in your question:

```
grouped = [[file_names[i], file_data[i]] for i,f in enumerate(file_names) if "podcast" not in file_names[i]]
file_names = [i[0] for i in grouped]
file_data = [i[1] for i in grouped]

print(file_data)
print(file_names)
```

Output:

```
['happiness is very nice', 'i need to go to gym']
['article_about_happiness', 'article about fitness']
```

Comment: This worked!!!... I was unaware of enumerate. Will learn them now. Thanks!!

Comment: @kumar glad to help, if any of these answers answered your question, take a look at [What to do if someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @chrisz Why are you begging and telling them about something which they've done two out of two times already, *yesterday*?

Comment: @StefanPochmann  Not trying to beg at all, I did say "If any of these answers", not just mine.  I believe all had merit.

Answer (score 3):

```
file_data, file_names = zip(
     *(i for i in zip(file_data, file_names) if 'podcast' not in i[-1])
)
```

Explanation:

1. I converted 2 lists to one where each element is a pair (data, name). That's how `zip` works.
2. I used list comprehension to only consider the pairs where the second item has no "podcast" in the name. Regex would be an overkill here. You can just do `if "substring" not in "string"` in Python.
3. Then, I unziped it to get 2 separate lists (using `zip(*list)`). I assigned them to the initial variables.